# Might two or more controllers share the same class instance in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, visibility, instances

I guess I have a conceptual anomaly in my twisted brain.

I'm trying to access the same instances (with the same attributes) (either libraries or methods) from several controllers, so when I change some attribute the other controllers are updated as well.

Any clarification shall be celebrated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20445622/how-to-define-a-global-variablevalue-in-codeigniter/20449660#20449660 , use a base controller.