# Codeigniter access object instance from included Class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a Codeigniter 3 Class called Fetch. It has the heritage from MY_Controller and sometimes it include a external library dinamicaly based on the existence of certain folder containing the required Class.

I want to have access to the $user object from those included Classes.
I even get an instance of CI from the included Class, but downt work.

Here is the example:

```
class Fetch extends MY_Controller
{
var $user;
...
$user = $this->getUserID($from);
$this->user = $user;
...
include_once $service_class . ".php"
}
```

I wanto to have acces of the $user object from the included Class:

```
class Mural
{
    private $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->model('mural_model');
    }

    public function _main()
    {
        var_dump($this->CI->user);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Uhmmm I'm reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20445622/how-to-define-a-global-variablevalue-in-codeigniter maybe has the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the solution is to declare the "global" variable to use in the application/core/MY_Controller.php and later use it as:

```
$this->CI->user;
```