# How to make the current year available in footer template

Tags: php, codeigniter

Very new to CI. Have completed only the [initial tutorial](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html) and now want to customise the code.

My question relates to customising the example code once that tutorial is complete.

**How can I define the current year once so that the footer template file can display the current year regardless of which controller is being invoked?**

There is a header template which includes the following code: `<?= esc($title) ?>` (also, is the `<?=` syntax specific to CI?)

I understand the `$title` variable contains the value populated in `$data['title']` within each of two controllers:

- as `$data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter` in Pages.php
- as `$data['title'] = $data['news']['title'];` in News.php
- and also as `$data = ['news'  => $model->getNews(), 'title' => 'News archive',];` in News.php (also - why is there a trailing comma here?)

The first customisation I would like to do is to put the current year into the footer template. To generate the current year, I am using `date("Y")`.

I have reviewed [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20445622/how-to-define-a-global-variablevalue-in-codeigniter) or [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527119/codeigniter-global-variable) other questions here but cannot solve it.

From reading those answers, it seems I have many options:

- Define a constant in the config file
- Create "MY_Controller" which can extend CI_Controller, Controller or BaseController (?) then update all controllers in the app so they extend MY_Controller ... but how exactly do I use MY_Controller to populate `$data['currentYear']` so that the footer template may reference it as `$currentYear`? (Or do I need to reference it a different way from the template?)
- Create "MY_Controller" as above (with all the same questions) but put the file in `application/libraries`
- ... or in `application\core`
- Create your own `defines.php` file and `require` that from `index.php` (? - there is no index.php in this example)
- Create your own helper function (where to put it?) which can then be  used "everywhere" in your code (but how? And when I tried using direct PHP in the footer file, it did not interpret the code - so how would you call a helper function from the footer template?)

I tried almost all of the above. I modified BaseController. I extended from BaseController to create my own controller then had all the other controllers extend my controller.

Obviously what I'm trying to achieve is to calculate the current year once so that the footer template can display it regardless of which controller is being invoked.

Comment: Why don't you use this `<?php echo date("Y"); ?>`?

Comment: Hi just create MY_Controller under application/core directory make $current_year as public property of that class, in MY_Controller constructor set this property $this->current_year = date('Y') and in you layout just call $this->current_year will work for you.

Comment: best way is to use this <?php echo date("Y"); ?>

Comment: Thanks @umefarooq - I tried that but was trying to reference it as $currentYear instead of $this-currentYear ... that may have been the issue. When I tried direct PHP it failed ... but now I wonder if it was simply a syntax error? In any case, this question still applies - current year is a trivial example, but the concept of setting a value "globally" for access within a template regardless of invoked controller - I am sure I will be coding that many times.

Comment: ok better option is in you MY_Controller $this->load->var(['currentYear'=>date('Y')]); now this will be available to you as $currentYear

Comment: Oh thank you. I'll try that out. Please do add it as an answer to the question so I can accept it..